# rake db:migrate with existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I'm trying to create models for an existing database.  I have read-only access to this database.  I've generated my models, but when I run rake db:migrate it wants to 'create' those tables.  Is there a way to satisfy rails need for migrating without actually creating these tables (since they already exist)?

Comment: delete migration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your models and tables already line up to Rails's naming scheme - `User` model => `users` table etc, and your models inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, then you don't need to run a migration at all (and can't anyway since migrations by definition change your database and you have read-only access).

If the table names don't match up to the model names, you can either change your model names, or set `self.table_name=` in your model. For example, if you have a `User` model but the table is called `accounts`, you can do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table = 'accounts'

  # other stuff here
end
```

Read here for more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D

Also, you should delete your migration files. If you want to see the schema in `db/schema.rb`, you can do a schema dump by running `rake db:schema:dump`. That should generate the file, assuming your settings are correct in `config/database.yml`.

Comment: What if I need to define a relationship between models (has_one, belongs_to, etc)?  Does rails need a migration to understand the relationships in the db....or can I just define it in the model?

Comment: If you need to get to your associations you can just do `has_one`, `belongs_to` etc. in the model. They will blow up if your tables don't have the right foreign keys and you try and use them, but they don't actually affect your database structure in any way.

Additionally, I would recommend adding the `readonly?` method to your model: `def readonly?; true; end`


With that, if you try and save the model, Rails will kick back an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exception, which you can then rescue from if you need to.

Comment: @ed_is_my_name was that helpful for you?